# Call method at set time when program is already running?

Tags: c#

Im trying to find some code that will run a method at 13:00 hrs if the program is running

Im using C sharp and creating a windows form

I started of by using a `timer` set to 1 min, and when `timer_tick` I tried an `if statement` to try

```
if (TimeDate.Now == new DateTime(0001, 01, 01, 08, 00))
```

Cheers

Comment: Exactly what is the problem here? Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: "Trying to find some code" -- just write it! That's kind of the cool thing about code, you can write your own :)

Comment: I started of by using a timer set to 1 min, and when timer_tick I tried an if statement to try (TimeDate.Now == new DateTime(0001, 01, 01, 08, 00)

Comment: @RyanGray So how long were you planning to wait for the current time to be 1 A.D.?  You'll be waiting for a long time for that condition to be true.  As in, forever long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `System.Threading.Timers.Timer` object;

Run the timer starting the next instance of your desired time and every 24 thereafter.

```
// TimerCallback object that wraps your method to call when timer elapses 
// (see end of answer)
var tc = new TimerCallback(DoStuffAt1300Hours);

// Tomorrow 2/25/14 at 1pm
var dt = new DateTime(2014, 2, 25, 13, 0, 0);

// dt - DateTime.Now = start timer in whatever time is between now and tomorrow at 1pm
// This is a delay, so effectively, the timer will start tomorrow at 1pm
// And it will run every 24 hours, calling the method DoStuffAt1300Hours()
var timer = new Timer(tc, null, dt - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

Create a callback that will execute what you want;

```
public static void DoStuffAt1300Hours(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hey it's 1pm!");
}
```